# Android-Creating resources for every screen density

Tags: android, layout, drawable

I know that android will pick the resources from the corresponding folders in the res file but I cant remember which densities are what. Can some one point me towards a quick reference of how I should create the resources based on a percentage of their original size.....for example drawable 100%, hdpi 120%, ect.  I need to know this so that I can just create new image resources for my layouts and then Ill store them in the drawable folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read about the densities [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: Yeah Ive read that many times before :) Im just looking for something that represents that in a percentage base so to speak so I can make my resources based on the percentage differences

Comment: Well, I don't know if you could find it, but you could calculate it perhaps. Normal size / small = 470 / 426 = 1,103. I think that makes it 10,3% bigger. So imho with this method you could calculate all the % differences.

Comment: Lol yeah I think all the turkey and beer Ive been consuming has made me lazy for the moment. Unless some one else posts some links to a reference list of some kind I guess thats what Ill do.

Comment: It's a bit boring perhaps, but you only have to do it once. Good luck!